# Django Model.save() works in a shell but not in a view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.5

For some reason when I call .save() on a model from within a view, the object isn't saved as a row in the database when called from a view. The id_seq table is incremented and has an id that doesn't exist in the table. The same code from the shell works as it should.

Example:

In a shell this will work:

```
app_version = AppVersion()
app_version.name = "some new name"
app_version.code = 880
app_version.save()
```

But in a View the same code does and the following happens

```
print str(app_version.id) // will return 99 for example
```

but:

```
select * from app_appversion order by id desc limit 1;

returns 98
```

the app_appversion_id_seq has 99 as the id.

Wtf is going on? This is the same problem as described here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/lBMSM4R3GqI

Django version is 1.5.1. No errors are caught or thrown. Didn't have this problem back on 1.4.8...

Comment: Are you using `transaction` ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#module-django.db.transaction

Comment: Thanks! But how come I don't get any errors when the TransactionMiddleware fails...?

Comment: My guess is, it might be because of the deprecation - it still exists only for compatibility with django <=1.3